# What is the Correct Model for Count Data with a Linear Conditional Mean?

Tags: regression, linear-model, count-data

This is my first question on Stack Exchange! I have looked extensively for an answer and it does not seem to exist so hopefully this will help many people with a similar problem.

I am working on a question where the dependent variable is a whole number (# of applications from a HS to a college) which is highly skewed. By my understanding, this makes it an excellent candidate for a traditional count model (Poisson, Negative Binomial, etcetera). The problem with these models is that the effect of covariates are multiplicative. Such models predict that a one unit increase in say the average SAT score at a given HS will increase applications far more at those schools which already send a lot of applications. However, when I split the sample by the dependent variable and estimate on each subsample using OLS, I find that some important variables have similar coefficients across the entire range of DV values. In other words, the conditional mean is linear in these variables.

Does anyone know of a count model that allows for a conditional mean which is linear in covariates over a certain range? I understand that a model which is purely linear probably wouldn't exist since it would predict negative values for some covariate combinations.

Thank you for your help.

Best,

Jordan

Comment: You might try Poisson GLM with identity link.

Comment: Michael M, your comment was very helpful as I was unaware of the distinction between the link function and the class of models. Using Negative Binomial GLM with an identity link I obtain coefficients similar to Linear OLS. One nice quality of the OLS is that I can easily estimate school fixed effects which control for time-constant unobservables. This does not seem possible with GLM.

Comment: The reason I want to use a Negative Binomial instead of OLS is that I would like to use my parameters to simulate a few different counterfactual scenarios. I need these simulation to generate whole numbers. However, if I could simply take the parameters from the OLS, estimate the conditional mean for each observation, and then draw from a negative binomial with that conditional mean that would be preferable. Then I could estimate a fully specified model with all the fixed effects. Does this sound like a reasonable approach?